# Dynamically added fragment crash immediately after creation in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to open new fragment dynamically. In MainActivity I create a new acitivity and this new activity has this function:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.akt_tryb_nauki)
    // komentarz dla testu
    val nowyFragment = TrybNaukiFragment()
    val transakcja = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    transakcja.replace(R.id.tryb_nauki, nowyFragment)
    transakcja.addToBackStack(null)
    transakcja.commit()
}
```

TrybNaukiFragment is my fragment and tryb_nauki is name of my layout. If I leave only 2 first lines (this ones starting from word super.. and setContentView) fragment opens without problems, but obviously function onCreateView() from TrybNaukiFragment() isn't working. I found a video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MdwhhksnOAM how to solve this, but after adding fragment with transaction my application crashes with this log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.ruslearn, PID: 20325
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child
    at android.widget.ScrollView.addView(ScrollView.java:370)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:326)
```

I don't understand why it appears, because without transaction it opens correctly and look at the akt_tryb_nauki.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".ui.tryb_nauki.TrybNaukiViewModel"
android:id="@+id/tryb_nauki"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/tryb_nauki_uklad"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
```

There is only one child in ScrollView. Does anyone know why it's not working?

Comment: It seems like you're trying to add the Fragment's layout to the `ScrollView` as well (making for 2 children, not just one). Why are you passing `R.id.tryb_nauki` to the `replace` call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
transakcja.replace(R.id.tryb_nauki, nowyFragment)
```

should be replaced with

```
transakcja.replace(R.id.frameLayoutActivity, nowyFragment)
```

Cause u want to replace the layout of the activity with the newfragment.